# Regex for everything *after* the first complete sentence (period and space) *after* N characters

Tags: regex, movabletype

I'd like to get smarter excerpts of sections of text. As I'll be using Movable Type's regex_replace function, I'm gonna be trying to grab everything after the first few sentences.

While `\..*` gets everything after the first period, that often leaves a too-short excerpt. How might I do the same thing (everything after the first period) but skipping the first 100 characters?

Alternatively, how would I just grab everything after, say, the second or third period?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with `regex_replace`, I'll use the PHP `preg_replace` function and you can adapt accordingly:

```
$truncated = preg_replace('/^(.{100}.*?\.).*$/s', '$1', $long);
```

Edit: I don't know what's up with the syntax highlighting on output treating the entire thing as a string, it looks fine in the preview.

And another version, which will try to be smart about not breaking up numbers with a decimal point (or other places a period might occur somewhere other than the end of a sentence):

```
$truncated = preg_replace('/^(.{100}.*?\.(?![a-z0-9])).*$/s', '$1', $long);
```

Explanation:

1. The part you want to keep is grouped with parentheses.
2. You'll keep at least 100 characters: `.{100}`
3. You'll then keep any following characters up to the first decimal point: `.*?\.`
4. In the second version, I used a negative lookahead—`(?![a-z0-9])`—which will cause the last part to continue on to the next decimal place if the period character is followed by either a number or letter.
5. Dot matches new-line (the `s` modifier at the end of the pattern). If Movable Type's `regex_replace` function takes a pattern without delimiters (the leading slash and the trailing `/s` in my pattern), you can use `(?s)` at the beginning of the pattern instead.
6. Use `$1` in the replacement to keep the first captured group.

Answer (score 0):

Complete sentence is vague, since different languages have different ways of encoding end-of-sentence. Let's assume that a space after a period is EOS:
`/^.*?\.\s+(?:.{N})(.*)/` Replace N by desired number.